# Why do I need `module.exports` in jest? How can I avoid it?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs, jestjs

I've met the trouble when trying to test my react js code using `jest` framework.

Let say this is mine component:

```
# coffee/global_widget.coffee
@GlobalWidget = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <div className='row'>
      <div className='col-md-12'>
        <TerminalWidget />
      </div>
    </div>

# coffee/terminal_widget.coffee
@TerminalWidget = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <div>Hey! This is the terminal!</div>
```

So, I want to test it using `jest`.

```
jest.dontMock '../coffee/global_widget'

describe 'GlobalWidget', ->
  global.React = require('react/addons')
  GlobalWidget = require('../coffee/global_widget')
  TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils

  globalWidgetForTest = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<GlobalWidget />)
  # body of the test
```

I have a trouble:

```
npm test

> terminal-ui@0.0.2 test /home/alex/my_project
> jest

Using Jest CLI v0.4.5
 FAIL  __tests__/global_widget-test.coffee (0.276s)
● GlobalWidget › it encountered a declaration exception
  - ReferenceError: GlobalWidget is not defined
```

If I append `module.exports = @GlobalWidget` to the `coffee/global_widget.coffee`, then I get `TerminalWidget is not defined`. What is `module.exports=` and why do I need to puts them for every component in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like jest doesnt have access to your global variables, so you need to export each file and require them as necessary.
you need to use module.exports because youre using the requirejs syntax with this line `GlobalWidget = require('../coffee/global_widget')`. What this does is isolate your code to prevent having a bunch of globally available code. this way, you import (using `require`) and export (using `module.exports = ...`) only the code you actually need. additionally, as in this case, it allows processes such as jest to gain access to files that are otherwise available.

if you absolutely dont want to use `requirejs` (which would be recommended to use) you can try adding them to your globals or fiddling with jests [config](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#config-setupenvscriptfile-string) to make these available prior to your test suite, though this will probably be more difficult than just exporting your modules

Comment: Thanks for answer! Can you explain what I should exactly edit in the config?